# Set output batch size from Azure Stream Analytics to Event Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

When outputting events from Azure Stream Analytics to an Azure Event Hub, multiple events may get batched into one message in the Event Hub. Is this batch size somehow configurable (or switch batching off entirely = batchsize==1)? Or is the maximum size just determined by the Event Hub message limit of 256KB?

For other ASA outputs such as Table storage or an Azure Function there is a setting for the batch size in the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no option to specify batchsize for eventhub output. If this configuration improves your scenario, please add it to user voice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics